# Display a specific page in a template

Tags: wordpress

i'm kind of stuck in Wordpress .

This is what i'm trying to do, i want to display a specific content page in a template page .

I have two values for `get_the_ID();`

in property-status/en-ventes/ : 79

in property-status/en-location/ : 93

It always displaying the page id 313, for the slug "en-ventes" it's fine but i wnat to display the page id 313 for the slug "en-location".

```
            <br />
            <?php  
            $idpage = get_the_ID(); 
            if($idpage = '79'){
            $my_query = new WP_Query('page_id=302');
            }
            else {
            $my_query = new WP_Query('page_id=313');
            }
            $arg= array($my_query);  
            ?> 

            <?php if (have_posts()) : while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();?>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand very well what you need, but, let's try:

```
$my_postid = 12;//This is page id or post id
$content_post = get_post($my_postid);
$content = $content_post->post_content;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
echo $content;
```

or

```
echo get_post_field('post_content', $post_id);
```

(you need to define de post_id ^)

or

```
$id=74; //change
$post = get_post($id);
$title = apply_filters('the_title', $post->post_title);
echo $title;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
echo $content;
```

and [check this](http://www.snilesh.com/resources/wordpress/wordpress-tips-and-tricks/wordpress-get-page-content-by-page-id/) and [this](http://eligeske.com/wordpress/display-single-pages-content-in-wp/)

Cheers.